# What's the font(s) used in the App Store badge?

Tags: font-identification, apple

What's the font used here?

[image: app store badge]
<sub>(source: [slashgear.com](https://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/app_store_badge_0708-540x196.png))</sub>

Comment: Have you tried any of the automated services?

Comment: @Farray I tried whatthefont.com, didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple uses Myriad for most all of its type (including this).

Comment: Myriad Semibold, to be exact.

Answer (score 3):

The font has been confirmed as Myriad Pro.